# edit connection in network manager puzzling me

Tags: internet, network-manager, connection

I'm slightly puzzled with the information listed in my edit connections of network manager.

I'm the only one who uses my laptop and I've only connected to one network via wireless.  However in the edit connections, it shows the laptop has been connected to three networks- one via wired and the other two connections via wireless (includes the password).  I know one of the wireless network connections but not the other two connections.

Other than the possibility of another person physically using my computer or me 'sleep-computing', ** is anyone able to help me resolve this puzzlement?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
**how else could the edit connection in network manager show that my computer has been connected to two other networks?

Comment: Wired usually connects automatically. For the wireless, password-protected one, someone had to type that password.

Comment: thanks alex.  without sparking a wave of paranoia for myself, I was trying to ask whether someone would be remotely accessing my computer in order to connect to another network and if so, could suggest some of prevention methods. (I have ufw turned on and have implemented other security techniques).

Comment: Even if someone was remotely connected to your computer, I find it hard to believe that they'd be able to use the network manager. It requires `X` in order to function, and remote accesses are almost always done without `X`. Open a question at http://security.stackexchange.com/ if you want to know security precautions.